# How to find out the versionCode of the previously installed app version after an app has been updated?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, version, updating

I am changing the way some data that is stored in the shared preferences in the new version of the app, hence I want to check in the new updated version , that if the version code before update was 21, then change the way data is stored in the preferences.

I could reset that preference data in the new version, but I would prefer not to do that.

Also, reading other answers, I realize that its best to store the version code in the preferences, but I have not done it yet. Is there some other place where the previous installed app version code stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some other place where the previous installed app version code stored?

Not that I know of. All you need to do is start fresh. An example...

```
// Set the version which will trigger the changes...
int changeNeeded = 22;

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
int previousVersion = prefs.getInt("version", -1);
if (previousVersion < changeNeeded) {

    // Make the changes

    // Get the current version and save to SharedPreferences as "version"
}
```

Put the above code in your MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity` and it will do what you need.

Comment: thankx squonk...that should work perfectly for me.
I was just thinking about it the wrong way. I should have been thinking that X change is needed from version 22 onward rather than X change is needed if app has updated from version 21.